# Any image hue shift available for Internet explorer like css filter in webkit

Tags: internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

I have seen filters like opacity in internet explorer. Is there already any filters to change hue of an image? Or is there even a possibility like say with an external `htc` file? (I really don't know how `htc` files work though)

I am looking for something like css3 filter hue in IE so that I can change red ball to blue green or yellow without using multiple images.

Comment: `htc` files are basically just javascript code in a custom wrapper, which is called when a CSS selector matches.

Comment: This might be the script you're looking for: https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill

Comment: @Spudley Hmm they support everything but `hue`

Comment: Have you tried "filter: hue-rotate(90deg)" ?

Comment: Hmm...I have to use something like hue-rotate too, for png transparent images, in Internet Explorer. Has anyone found any solutions to this? Is there an alternative to hue-rotate for IE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change images colors in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220692/how-to-change-images-colors-in-internet-explorer)