# How to change images colors in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I've succeded changing png images colors in Chrome and Firefox with CSS3.

My code:

```css
#second_image{
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(59deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(59deg);
}
```

```html
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/uGjlkRz.png' />
<img id='second_image' src='http://i.imgur.com/uGjlkRz.png' />
```

See also [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hksoa9sa/).

My problem is that I don't know how to do the same thing in Internet Explorer. At least from v9 up of IE. Is it even possible? I accept even JavaScript or jQuery solutions or some sort of ideas.

Comment: IE users will just have to manage. Good luck..JS to do would be very hard...if, indeed it is even possible.

Comment: No can't do @Paulie_D, I offered a very simplified code of my problem. I need this for an app I'm creating where on click of a button I have to change the colors of images at some point.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I've already searched for some time for a solution. On SO and on Google. No succes. That's why I asked here after some days of research. From what I found and tried I came to the conclusion that may not be possible. Again, so you understand @Paulie_D, that's why I asked here. Maybe someone else knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible in any version of Internet Explorer.

Here's an overview of which browsers have support for CSS Filters at the moment I'm writing this post (March 25th, 2016) :

[image]

For an up-to-date overview, [**take a look at CanIUse**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

While [**there IS a polyfill for CSS filters**](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill), it has no support for IE 10+, older Presto-based Operas, Opera Mini or Android browser.

Also, there's only support for the following filters :

- grayscale (only 0% or 100% values in IE)
- sepia (only 0% or 100% values in IE)
- blur
- invert (only 0% or 100% values in IE)
- brightness
- drop-shadow

---

#### Alternative approach

One possible workaround would be to use a backend language like PHP to process your file.

Consider an `index.php` file with the following code :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

function rgb2hsl($r, $g, $b) {
    $var_R = ($r / 255);
    $var_G = ($g / 255);
    $var_B = ($b / 255);

    $var_Min = min($var_R, $var_G, $var_B);
    $var_Max = max($var_R, $var_G, $var_B);
    $del_Max = $var_Max - $var_Min;

    $v = $var_Max;

    if ($del_Max == 0) {
        $h = 0;
        $s = 0;
    } else {
        $s = $del_Max / $var_Max;

        $del_R = ( ( ( $var_Max - $var_R ) / 6 ) + ( $del_Max / 2 ) ) / $del_Max;
        $del_G = ( ( ( $var_Max - $var_G ) / 6 ) + ( $del_Max / 2 ) ) / $del_Max;
        $del_B = ( ( ( $var_Max - $var_B ) / 6 ) + ( $del_Max / 2 ) ) / $del_Max;

        if ($var_R == $var_Max)
            $h = $del_B - $del_G;
        else if ($var_G == $var_Max)
            $h = ( 1 / 3 ) + $del_R - $del_B;
        else if ($var_B == $var_Max)
            $h = ( 2 / 3 ) + $del_G - $del_R;

        if ($h < 0)
            $h++;
        if ($h > 1)
            $h--;
    }

    return array($h, $s, $v);
}

function hsl2rgb($h, $s, $v) {
    if ($s == 0) {
        $r = $g = $B = $v * 255;
    } else {
        $var_H = $h * 6;
        $var_i = floor($var_H);
        $var_1 = $v * ( 1 - $s );
        $var_2 = $v * ( 1 - $s * ( $var_H - $var_i ) );
        $var_3 = $v * ( 1 - $s * (1 - ( $var_H - $var_i ) ) );

        if ($var_i == 0) {
            $var_R = $v;
            $var_G = $var_3;
            $var_B = $var_1;
        } else if ($var_i == 1) {
            $var_R = $var_2;
            $var_G = $v;
            $var_B = $var_1;
        } else if ($var_i == 2) {
            $var_R = $var_1;
            $var_G = $v;
            $var_B = $var_3;
        } else if ($var_i == 3) {
            $var_R = $var_1;
            $var_G = $var_2;
            $var_B = $v;
        } else if ($var_i == 4) {
            $var_R = $var_3;
            $var_G = $var_1;
            $var_B = $v;
        } else {
            $var_R = $v;
            $var_G = $var_1;
            $var_B = $var_2;
        }

        $r = $var_R * 255;
        $g = $var_G * 255;
        $B = $var_B * 255;
    }
    return array($r, $g, $B);
}

function imagehue(&$image, $angle) {
    if ($angle) {
        if ($angle % 360 == 0)
            return;
        $width = imagesx($image);
        $height = imagesy($image);

        for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
            for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
                $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
                $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
                $alpha = ($rgb & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
                list($h, $s, $l) = rgb2hsl($r, $g, $b);
                $h += $angle / 360;
                if ($h > 1)
                    $h--;
                list($r, $g, $b) = hsl2rgb($h, $s, $l);
                imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $r, $g, $b, $alpha));
            }
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['src'])) {
    switch (exif_imagetype($_GET['src'])) {
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            header('Content-type: image/png');
            $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_GET['src']);
            imagealphablending($image, false);
            imagesavealpha($image, true);
            imagehue($image, isset($_GET['hue-rotate']) ? $_GET['hue-rotate'] : FALSE);
            imagepng($image);
            imagedestroy($image);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
            $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);
            imagehue($image, isset($_GET['hue-rotate']) ? $_GET['hue-rotate'] : FALSE);
            imagejpeg($image);
            imagedestroy($image);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If you put that file at a server that supports PHP, you could use it like this:

```html
<img src='http://www.johnslegers.com/hue-rotate/?src=http://i.imgur.com/uGjlkRz.png' />
<img src='http://www.johnslegers.com/hue-rotate/?src=http://i.imgur.com/uGjlkRz.png&hue-rotate=59' />
<img src='http://www.johnslegers.com/hue-rotate/?src=http://i.imgur.com/uGjlkRz.png&hue-rotate=95' />
<img src='http://www.johnslegers.com/hue-rotate/?src=http://i.imgur.com/uGjlkRz.png&hue-rotate=163' />
<img src='http://www.johnslegers.com/hue-rotate/?src=http://i.imgur.com/uGjlkRz.png&hue-rotate=234' />
```

Comment: @epascarello It is also possible in Opera! Of course, Opera and Edge are both not Internet Explorer, so...technicalities.

Comment: I've came across those support details. I don't pray for the same solution. I need some sort of alternative.

Comment: @Anonymous : Check my updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: I didn't downvoted this. Unfortunately I can't use PHP for this project. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -3):

each browser have one kind of engine, so, try use it, probably will work in all browsers

```
  -webkit-filter: //do whatever you want;
  -moz-filter: //do whatever you want;
  -ms-filter: //do whatever you want;
  -o-filter: //do whatever you want;
  filter: //do whatever you want;
  filter: //do whatever you want; /* Firefox 4+ */
  filter: //do whatever you want; /* IE 6-9 */
```

http://labs.voronianski.com/css3-grayscale/

Comment: why the downvotes? the people put a downvote and no t explain why